# Linq to SQL replacing related entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a `Client` entity and `PostCode` entity in Linq to SQL model. The `Clients` table in database contains `client_postcode` column which is a FK column to postalcode column in `PostCode` table, which is a varchar column primary key for PostCode table.

When updating Client, in my code I do this

```
        // postcode
        updating.PostCode = (from p in ctx.PostCodes
                             where p.postalcode.Equals(client.PostCode.postalcode)
                             select p).First();
```

where `client` object is provided from ASP.NET MVC View form. This code seems to set the PostCode related entity fine. But when calling SubmitChanges() I receive the following exception:

*Value of member 'postalcode' of an object of type 'PostCode' changed. A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed. Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead.*

So I am currently unable to change the related entity. How is that done in Linq to Sql?

UPDATE:

After further review and troubleshooting I found out that the problem is in ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel() call. If I call UpdateModel() to update the existing entity with the edited data, something is wrong with the FK assignement for PostCode. If I don't call UpdateModel and do it by hand, it works.
Any ideas what goes wrong in UpdateModel() that it can't set the relationship to foreign key entities correctly?

**I am updating this question and starting a bounty. The question is simplified. How to successfully use L2S and UpdateModel() to work when updating items (with related entities as FK) in ASP.NET MVC Edit views?**

Comment: Are you sure you're not changing the PostCode object at all? Can you post the code you call before the SubmitChanges() method is called?

Comment: This is all I am doing to PostCode related entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are receiving **PostCode.postalcode in the http post request**.

Based on how model binding works, the **UpdateModel** call **updates .PostCode.postalcode of the model** you are passing to it.

**Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470388.aspx) to include or exclude specific properties**.

Comment: this is so far the closest answer though I cannot confirm it just yet. Upvoting.

Comment: Thanks eglasius. This definitely worked for me too. Fantastic solution. Does exactly what I needed. In my case, the ORM was trying to forcibly insert a new complex child object called "StatusID" even though I wasn't updating the Status at all and Status wasn't contained in my form/view either. So I just called the overload like: UpdateModel(ExistingRecord, String.Empty, null, new string[] { "StatusID" }); and it works!!!!! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't  `updating.client_postcode = client.client_postcode;`  accomplish what you want?

`Client.PostCode` should be looked up on seek based on client_postocde.

Comment: If I do this, it says: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do what you are trying, you cannot change the `Postcode` like that.

James' idea is in the right direction.

`Updatemodel()` takes the matching values from the `Formcollection`

How do these values come in the `Formcollection`? What are their `keys`?

basically there are 2 ways in editing an object.

option 1:

all the value names you want to update have corresponding keys in the `Formcollection`, which leaves you just to call `UpdateModel()` of the **original** object. do `SubmitChanges()`

option 2:

Get the original object, change it's values manually (because the keys dont correspond) and do `SubmitChanges()`

you are tying to change a link, you cant do that. you can only edit the updating.client_postcode which in this case is a string?

**Can you please copy the whole action here? So I can write some code for you without gambling.**

Comment: I had my controller action both with just UpdateModel() (in which case I get the exception mentioned in my question) and without it and manually setting the properties of a original object (in this case there is an exception that I provided in my comment to James' answer).

Comment: Also what you say is wrong, you can and should change the related entity by changing the association property not the FK itself, look here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/744b2c6a-ecb8-44bf-b72a-dc1b85b34342/

Comment: can you just post the whole action method? because clearly something is wrong... and it's not shown in the code you provided.

Comment: I find it likely that the OP is telling you what is. I find it perfectly reasonable than the UpdateModel is getting  postcode.postalcode in the form collection and trying to update it. @mare can you confirm? / check my answer.